# Remove WordPress capabilities from users who no longer have the role

Tags: php, wordpress

My WordPress site has gone through several membership plugins over the years and with each change I've created new custom user roles. I found out this morning through troubleshooting another problem (Thanks, Prasad K), that even though I delete a role and reassign the user to a new role that the capabilities of the prior role may remain.

For example, one of my users shows this in their wp_usermeta : `'a:2:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;s:8:"new_lead";b:1;}'`

I have not had a subscriber role for at least 4 years. Other users have many more additions that don't exist.

What’s best practice for removing these excess capabilities from users when the roles no longer exist?

**Edit:**

Unfortunately User Role Editor is not able to see the roles/capabilities. Both the free and paid version do not help. Any other suggestions?

Thanks

Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Download [User Role Editor](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)

Add the **Subscriber** role. Then goto users and update the users with subscriber to the role that you want to change them too.

Refer to [this link](http://shinephp.com/user-role-editor-wordpress-plugin/) for a detailed way to change the user roles.

**Alternatively**

You can edit the roles via phpmyadmin. Have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925219/sql-query-to-bulk-change-roles-in-wordpress-in-the-database), specifically the answer to getting the sql query for modifying the role and then we just have to make a `foreach()` loop via funtions or a more advanced SQL query to run in phpmyadmin for each user with the capability of "subscriber" to your desired alternate role. Note: **A backup of the database should be done before any changes!**

Comment: HI @Aliqua, Unfortunately remove_role() doesn't work. When I display all roles with something like the code below. Subscriber etc does not appear. 

`global $wp_roles;
$roles = $wp_roles->roles; 
 
// print it to the screen
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $roles, true ) . '</pre>';`

Comment: Hey @Aliqua. I've reached out to User Role Editor and I'm waiting on a reply. I'm skeptical, I don't think the plugin is going to recognize the roles as they don't show up in the footer.php script above. I'll follow up when I've received a reply.

Comment: Hey @Aliqua, User Role Editor got back to and said all versions of the plugin are capable of showing and deleting unused roles. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to have helped. Happy coding!

Comment: Hey @Aliqua. I tried both the free and licensed version of User Role Editor and neither are able to help. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hey @Aliqua, User Role Editor followed up with me. He said "If a role is deleted from the array before it is revoked from the user, that wordpress looks at it as a capability granted to the user directly, and not via role". That explains it, cause that's what I did. I thought deleting the role would also remove capabilities from the user. He said user role editor will remove the capability, but I'll need to go user by user. Luckily I only have to do it 1300* times :) . I follow up later this morning after I've tested a single user. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers mate. I'd refer to my updated answer re: do an SQL query, find the generated query line to edit the 'subscriber', then ask a new question re how to bulk edit. Wish you all the best!

Comment: Thanks @Aliqua, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words